# Removing Punctuation from varchar

Tags: punctuation

I looked at the other threads related to this topic and tried to incorporate the information in my query...without success.  I want to compare to data fields without taking into consideration punctuation.  I tried PATINDEX, I tried STUFF with PATINDEX and it removes some, but not all, of the punctuation.  Here is my masked query.  Any feedback appreciated.  My SQL skills are whatever I can read or asking others.  TIA

SELECT TABLE_1.FIELD_1,
       TABLE_1.FIELD_2,
       STUFF(TABLE_1.FIELD_3, PATINDEX('%[.,&!<>;:$- ]%',TABLE_1.FIELD_3),1, '') AS FIELD_3,
       STUFF(TABLE_2.FIELD_4, PATINDEX('%[.,&!<>;:$- ]%',TABLE_2.FIELD_4),1,'') AS FIELD_4,
       TABLE_1.FIELD_6,
       TABLE_1.FIELD_7,
       TABLE_1.FIELD_8,
       TABLE_1.FIELD_9,
       TABLE_1.FIELD_10,
       TABLE_1.FIELD_11
INTO #BOOK1
FROM TABLE_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 ON 
    TABLE_1.FIELD_2 = TABLE_2.FIELD_5

SELECT * FROM #BOOK1 
WHERE LEFT(#BOOK1.FIELD_3,10) <> 
      LEFT(#BOOK1.FIELD_4,10) AND
      #BOOK1.CLE_PROFILE_STATE IN ('VALUE_1','VALUE_2')
ORDER BY FIELD_3

Answer (score 0):

Sql has a replace function that will let you strip a character or sequence out. It's a bit ugly but you can nest lots of them or create a function.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I saw the nesting and it was, indeed, ugly.  I'll ask the dba for a function.  I'm trying to learn more so I'm more self-sufficient.  Appreciate the reply.